# Terraform: upload file from ec2 linux to s3 bucket using lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to transfer a file that exists in ec2 Linux at location : /tmp/sample.txt  to existing S3 bucket using lambda function. Below steps are done:

1/ Create an IAM role with s3FullAccess and Ec2FullAccess

2/ Create a s3 bucket and ec2 instance

3/ create a lambda function and try to run the below code.

```
import json
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client      = boto3.client('ec2')
    s3          = boto3.client('s3')
    ids         = ['i-03c19889202a0bad2']
    status = client.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=ids)
    s3.upload_file('/tmp/mybackupFile.txt','dev-dent-clinicdoc','mybackupFileCopied.txt') 
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body' : json.dumps('Hello from lambda')
    }
```

This is my tf code :

```
locals{
  lambda_zip_location    = "prod/dentinnov/backupEc2ToS3.zip"
}

# create an archive inclduing the source file "lambda.py" then put it in output_path location 
data "archive_file" "init" {
  type              = "zip"                                       
  source_file       = "${path.module}/lambda.py"                  
  output_path       = local.lambda_zip_location                   
}

# create lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_function" "backup_lambda" {
  description       = "Lambda function for dentinnov ec2 instances backup to s3"
  filename          = local.lambda_zip_location
  function_name     = "prod_backup_lambda"
  role              = var.role                        
  handler           = "lambda.lambda_handler"                     
  source_code_hash  = filebase64sha256(local.lambda_zip_location) 
  runtime           = "python3.7"
  timeouts          { create = "10m" }
```

Text file is created in ec2 instance. Check done :

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-44-185 /]$ ls -la /tmp/mybackupFile.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 24 Jun 23 07:50 /tmp/mybackupFile.txt
```

When run the function lambda, it gives error :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/mybackupFile.txt'",
  "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda.py\", line 10, in lambda_handler\n    s3.upload_file('/tmp/mybackupFile.txt','dev-dent-clinicdoc','mybackupFileCopied.txt')\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py\", line 131, in upload_file\n    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py\", line 279, in upload_file\n    future.result()\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py\", line 106, in result\n    return self._coordinator.result()\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py\", line 265, in result\n    raise self._exception\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py\", line 255, in _main\n    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/upload.py\", line 549, in _submit\n    upload_input_manager.provide_transfer_size(transfer_future)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/upload.py\", line 237, in provide_transfer_size\n    transfer_future.meta.call_args.fileobj))\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/s3transfer/utils.py\", line 245, in get_file_size\n    return os.path.getsize(filename)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py\", line 50, in getsize\n    return os.stat(filename).st_size\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where is your TF code? Also `/tmp/mybackupFile.txt` is on instance? So why are you looking for it in your lambda function?

Comment: Hello Marcin, I have added my TF code as per your request. `/tmp/mybackupFile.txt` is on ec2 instance

Comment: The proper way to execute commands on instance from your lambda would be through [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html). So you would have to modify your code to use that.

Comment: Hello Marcin, I'm confuse. How this command `s3.upload_file('/tmp/mybackupFile.txt','dev-dent-clinicdoc','mybackupFileCopied.txt')`  knows that `/tmp/mybackupFile.txt` is located in ec2 instance ?

Comment: It does not know that. That's why it fails. You have to do it either through Run Command, or by sshing into the instance from your lambda.

Comment: So in my current above py code,  where the script is looking for /tmp/mybackupFile.txt, in S3 ?

Comment: It seems that it looks in the lambda environment package, and not in the EC2 file system. I would suggest you upload it using aws-cli from the terminal. if you have the right role attached to the EC2, you don't even need to provide credentials. All of this can be done from Terraform also.